# Cosmos DB Emulator refusing connections for the gremlin endpoint

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage-emulator, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have an asp.net core mvc application which I test locally against the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator and most of the time it works fine, but once in a while after I start up the emulator I get the following error

```
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I always start it up with the same command line:

```
"c:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe" /EnsureGremlinEndpoint
```

I can always connect using document database using the normal default port on 8081 to initialize the database, create a collection and import data to it, but when that is done and I want to connect to the gremlin api (port 8901) sometimes it does not work. When the error occurs it seems like no matter what I do solves the problem, but after a random amount of time (usually days) the gremlin endpoint works again. The randomness of both the error and the error going away is very frustrating.

Any tips would be helpful!

Comment: I have tried to change the enableSsl between true and false but this does change the error.

Comment: Which version of Gremlin.NET are you using in your application? Also can you provide an example code that is used to connect to the gremlin endpoint?

Comment: I have given up on solving this one and just spend azure credits and run it directly towards the cloud since the cloud connection always works... and not a single person seems to have any idea what could cause this behavior.